# vb.net check if a button clicked on another new form

Tags: vb.net

i have 2 forms in a project form1 and form2 in visual studio 2013.
form2 consists 2 buttons (button1 and button2)

form1 has a timer event where form 2 will fire in certain cases.
So i need code in Form1 to know if a button clicked in form2.

i tried these codes in form1 but not working:

```
if form2.button2_Click = true then
msgbox("Button 2 clicked")
end if
```

Please can someone help me with this and do the needfull.(i want to do this from form1 only)

Comment: A `Button_click` is an event - they fire when the user clicks and thats it, have the form with the button invoke a method on the other form telling it the button was clicked

Comment: Thank you Plutonix i got the method

Answer (score 1):

in form2

```
Public Class Form2

Public Event SimulateForm1ButtonClick()

Private Sub MetroTile2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As   System.EventArgs) Handles MetroTile2.Click

    RaiseEvent SimulateForm1ButtonClick()


End Sub
```

And in Form1

```
Public Class Form1
Private WithEvents myform As New Form2


Private Sub frm2_SimulateForm1ButtonClick() Handles myform.SimulateForm1ButtonClick

msgbox("Sucecss!!!! called from form 2")
End Sub
```